# UINavigationBar is white when it's bg color is set to black

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I don't understand why it is so. Here is my code:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
UINavigationBar.appearance().translucent = false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `backgroundColor` to `barTintColor` and

try this

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
UINavigationBar.appearance().translucent = false
```

**e.g**

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool
{
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    UINavigationBar.appearance().translucent = false

    return true
}
```

or use

```
   self.navigationController!.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.translucent = false
```

**e.g**

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.translucent = false

      }
```